# How to use an interceptor to add an api_key

Tags: angular

I know that I could do the next thing without using an interceptor, but I'm trying to figure it out adding that extra param on every httpRequest. I've been reading about (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18812) this issue which duplicates the params. I tried the work-around provided but it doesn't work.

I saw an easy way doing something like **const newReq = req.url + 'api_key'** (please don't take it literally, It doesn't work like that)  a time ago but I can't remember. Anyone could let me know how to get the expected behavior?

Expected behavior -> [https://api.xxx.com/xxx&api_key='api_key'](https://api.xxx.com/xxx&api_key=%27api_key%27)

Current behavior ->https://api.xxx.com/xxx&api_key=undefined&api_key='whatever'

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiKeyInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   let newParams = new HttpParams({fromString: req.params.toString()});
   newParams = newParams.append('api_key', '123123123asdasdasd');

   const requestClone = req.clone({
     params: newParams
   });
   return next.handle(requestClone);
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**set** should do the trick:

```
newParams = newParams.set('api_key', '123123123asdasdasd');
```